# Extensibility Package Debugging in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-extensions

I try to debug visual studio package. I have installed visual studio 2012 SDK and have created new empty visual studio package (did not set menu, tool and editor checkboxes). 
I'm setting breakpoint into package's constructor:

```
public MyPackage()
{
    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, 
        "Entering constructor for: {0}", this.ToString())); // This line
}
```

But if I run an experimental version of IDE, visual studio will not load my package.
What I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your package to auto-load: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166762.aspx